# NetVips Mosiac how to calculate the merge point

Tags: c#, vips

Doing some work to merge a bunch of images into one large image. I found the vips library and the mosaic function ([Link to vips doc](https://www.libvips.org/API/current/libvips-mosaicing.html#vips-mosiac) which worked how I want it to work in an [example](https://github.com/kleisauke/net-vips/blob/master/samples/NetVips.Samples/Samples/OnePointMosaic.cs). The issue I'm running into is how to calculate the merge point. It doesn't look like vips has a way to do this out of the box, and I haven't found a different C# library that accomplishes finding that merge point. Any pointer or places to look would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the libvips `mosaic` operation:

https://www.libvips.org/API/current/libvips-mosaicing.html#vips-mosaic

You give it an approximate overlap, it searches for the true overlap, then calls `merge` for you. You can use the params to control the search window and the accuracy of the initial overlap. By default you need to be within about 10 pixels (from memory).

The "Description" section at the top of that page has a general introduction.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I didn't realize that I had a bit of wiggle room in the overlap pixels. Luckily the file I'm stitching tell me where they are in the mosiac, so I was able to know hey I'm merging this one with the tile on the right and just get a pixel on the right edge.